# Is there a way to check if beforeSave is called for a new Parse object, or for updating an existing object?

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I need to check (and take appropriate action) if an object is just being created, or an already-existing object is being updated with new values. Is there any way to check this accurately?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes there is. A new object will not have an id yet, so you can check the object if it has an id.

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("MyClass", function (request, response) {
    var object = request.object;
    if (!object.id) {
       // this is a new object
    }
});
```

Comment: There's also the `isNew()` instance method.